# Finite groups $G$ with epimomorphisms $\phi_1,\phi_2 : F_2 \rightarrow G$ s.t. $|\phi_1(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)|\neq|\phi_2(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)|$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, group-homomorphism

Can someone give an example of a finite (ideally nonabelian) group $G$ and two surjective homomorphisms
$\phi_1,\phi_2 : F_2 \rightarrow G$ (where $F_2$ is the free group on the generators $x,y$), such that $\phi_1(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)$ and $\phi_2(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)$ have different orders?

Is this possible?

Are there conditions on $G$ that make this impossible? (In other words, as suggested by  Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, are there conditions on $G$, still assumed to be a 2-generated group such that the commutator $[a,b]$ always has the same order for any pair of generators $a,b$?)

thanks

Comment: A less convoluted way of asking your second question is: what condition on $G$ garantees that there is a number $n$ such that whenever two elements $a$ and $b$ generate $G$ then $[a,b]$ has order $n$.

Comment: A simple condiion is of course that $G$ cannot be generated by two elements :-)

Comment: (I have no idea of why you think this is a simple question, by the way!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the elements $a=(12345678)$, $b=(12)$ and $c=(12)(34)$.

The sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ both generate $S_8$. Compute the orders of the corresponding commutators.

Comment: Nice. anything on the second question?

I'm thinking that maybe some groups of order 2p might have this property (p prime)

Comment: There are not a lot of groups of order $2p$... why don't you just check instead of guess?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's just that my knowledge of group theory is very basic. My guess came from topology. Basically, the question can be phrased as (using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula) - do there exist Galois ramified covers of a torus ramified at most above one point that are of different genera.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat trivial general *sufficient* condition is that $G'$ is cyclic of prime order $p$. Then the commutator of any pair of generators is an element of order $p$. (The two non-abelian groups of order $p^{3}$ provide examples here.)

This is not *necessary*, however. In the group
$$
G = \langle x, y : x^{p^{3}} = y^{p^{2}} = 1, [x, y] = x^{p} \rangle,
$$
where $p$ is a prime (perhaps an odd one), if $G = \langle a, b \rangle$, then $[a, b]$ has order $p^{2}$.

The reason is that in a (non-abelian, say) group $H = \langle a, b \rangle$ we have that $H'$ is the normal closure of $\langle [a, b] \rangle$. In this particular group $G$, we have that $G' = \langle a^{p} \rangle$ is cyclic of order $p^{2}$, with all of its subgroups $\{1\}, \langle a^{p^{2}} \rangle, \langle a^{p} \rangle$ characteristic in $G$. So if for two generators $a, b$ we have that $[a,b]$ has order less than $p^{2}$, then $[a, b] \le \langle a^{p^{2}} \rangle$, and the normal closure of $\langle [a, b] \rangle$ is definitely not $G'$.

So **a more general *sufficient* condition is that the derived subgroup of the two-generator group is cyclic**, because all the subgroups of a cyclic group are characteristic. (So we get more examples here, for instance the dihedral groups.)

Once more, this is not necessary, as the example of $A_{4}$ shows. This example suggests that **another *sufficient* condition is that $G'$ is elementary abelian**, so that all of its non-trivial elements have the same prime order. (Examples here are provided by the affine group of a finite line, that is, the semidirect products $F \rtimes F^{\star}$, where $F$ is the additive groups of a finite field, and $F^{\star}$ its multiplicative group, acting on $F$ by multiplication. When $F = \operatorname{GF}(4)$, we get $A_{4}$.)

---

**Addendum** I extract from the comments below an observation. Suppose $G'$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$. Then $G$ satisfies the condition provided the following holds:

> if the exponent of $G'$ is $p^{e}$, then $\Omega_{e-1}(G')$ is a *proper* subgroup of $G'$.

Here $\Omega_{f}(H)$ is the subgroup of the $p$-group $H$ generated by all elements of order at most $p^{f}$. And the statement holds since, as noted above, if $G = \langle x, y \rangle$, then $G'$ is the normal closure of $\langle [x, y] \rangle$. If $[a, b]$ does not have order $p^{e}$, then $\langle [x, y] \rangle \le \Omega_{e-1}(G') < G'$, thus the normal closure of $\langle [a, b] \rangle$ is not $G'$, and so $a, b$ do not generate $G$.

Comment: I am surprised to see some $G$ of order $2^6$ with $[a,b]$ of order 4 with $G'\cong C_2 \times C_4$. I had hoped that $G'$ being homocyclic might be necessary and sufficient amongst metabelian groups, but this is not the case.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, that's a very good example. Is there any odd equivalent, or is it just $p = 2$?

Comment: Odd equivalents as well (just from computer search). I'll find one that is easy to see by hand.

Comment: Here is an easy one to verify: $$G=\langle a,b,c : a^{p^2} = b^{p^2} = c^{p^2} = 1, [b,a]=c, [c,a]=b^p, [c,b]=1 \rangle$$ Then $G=\langle a,b \rangle$, $\Phi(G)=\langle a^p, b^p, c \rangle$, so every generating set has some “b” so every commutator has some “c”, and every commutator has order $p^2$. $G'=\langle b^p,c\rangle$ is not homocyclic.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, good example. It seems to me that for finite, $2$-generated $p$-groups $G$, there is a rather general sufficient condition on $G'$ that ensures that the condition holds. This is that if $\exp(G') = p^{e}$, then $\Omega_{e-1}(G')$ is a *proper* subgroup of $G'$. In particular, the condition holds whenever $G'$ is abelian, or regular.

Answer (score 0):

Take $G=H_1\oplus H_2$, where g.c.d.$(|H_1|,|H_2|)=1$, $\phi_i: F\to H_i$.

Comment: They want the $\phi_i$ surjective.

Comment: Your homomorphisms aren't surjective.

Also, no abelian group will work, since the commutator $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ will almost map to the identity in any abelian group.

Comment: sorry, what I meant by "almost" was "always". My sentence doesn't make sense grammatically as written. heh